# filter text file rows by certain column without quotation marks

Tags: linux, unix, csv, awk

so I have a file that I'd like to only get certain rows from, but unfortunately the strings within those rows aren't surrounded by quotation marks. How can I filter these rows based on the 2nd column value??
Eg I have:

```
string a,string b,string c,string d,string e
string 1,string 2,string 3,string 4,string 5
string f,string b,string h,string i,string j
string 6,string 7,string 8,string 9,string 0
```

And I want in a new file only:

```
string a,string b,string c,string d,string e
string f,string b,string h,string i,string j
```

I'm trying to use the command:

```
awk -F '","'  'BEGIN {OFS=","} { if (toupper($2) == "STRING B")  print }' input.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to include double quotes on setting the  FS value.

```
$ awk -F,  'BEGIN {OFS=","} { if (toupper($2) == "STRING B")  print }' file
string a,string b,string c,string d,string e
string f,string b,string h,string i,string j
```

Comment: Ahh, of course. Great, thanks. Will mark as correct ASAP

Comment: @EdMorton just modified the op's command. But Wintermute posted the modified form.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work if you use `-F,` instead of `-F '","'`. A somewhat more idiomatic way to do the same is

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'toupper($2) == "STRING B"' input.csv
```

In awk code, a condition without an associated action means to perform the default action (printing) if the condition is true, so this comes to the same effect with less fluff.